# How to remove NaN values from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis, data-cleaning

I'm trying to clean a dataset and observed few features are of type : non-null Float type.
The values contain - NaN

I tried below code :

```
cleaned_customer_data.fillna(cleaned_customer_data.mean()).head()
```

This result with 0 record.

Also, i tried -

```
cleaned_customer_data.fillna(cleaned_customer_data.mean())
```

It doesn't change NaN values to mean.

Data Sample :

```
FEATURE1
--------
NaN
2.0
NaN
NaN
NaN
1.294
```

Am i doing something wrong here, please guide.

Comment: Can you add some data sample? Is possible missing values are strings? what is `print (cleaned_customer_data[cleaned_customer_data.isna().any(axis=1)])` ?

Comment: It couldn't be string as datatype is float64.

Comment: So `print (cleaned_customer_data[cleaned_customer_data.isna().any(axis=1)])` return rows with missing values?

Comment: Yes, It returned missing values. (NaN)

Comment: hmmm, do you assign back? `cleaned_customer_data = cleaned_customer_data.fillna(cleaned_customer_data.mean())` ?

Comment: Yes,
tried - 
cleaned_customer_data=cleaned_customer_data.fillna(cleaned_customer_data.mean())
cleaned_customer_data.head()

and still the same.

Comment: Can you add some data sample to question?

Comment: So `print (df.dtypes)` are floats for all columns which are not removed NaNs?

Comment: Yes, it resulted in float64

Comment: Found the issue. The column values are all NaN. This occured after data pre-cleaning which resulted in dropping rows which had values in this features based on some condition.   Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First, calculate the mean for the required column:

`mean_value=cleaned_customer_data['FEATURE1'].mean()`

Then, fill the NaN values with the obtained mean:

`cleaned_customer_data['FEATURE1'].fillna(value=mean_value, inplace=True)`

Display your df:

`cleaned_customer_data`

Comment: It is same like `cleaned_customer_data = cleaned_customer_data.fillna(cleaned_customer_data.mean())` - It not working for OP. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72470709/how-to-remove-nan-values-from-dataframe#comment128022576_72470709

Comment: Thanks Nina, Found the issue. The column values are all NaN. This occured after data pre-cleaning which resulted in dropping rows which had values in this features based on some condition.

Comment: Please include an explanation with your answer to help readers understand how this works, and solves the problem. You can click the edit button at the bottom of your answer to add an explanation. Additionally, have a read of [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

first, you need to calculate the mean :

```
mean_df = df.loc[df['FEATURE1'].notna()]['FEATURE1'].mean()
```

Then you assign the value of the mean where there is a NaN:

```
df.loc[df['FEATURE1'].isna(),'FEATURE1'] = mean_df
```